# Conversion error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework. I'm trying to retrieve data from the database using a LINQ query and Entity Framework.

```
IEnumerable<Gate> lstGate = from tbsite in dc.tblSites
                            select new Gate
                            {
                              CalledInAt = DateTime.Parse(tbsite.CalledInAt.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-GB", false)),
                              RemoteType = tbsite.RemoteType,
                              NoOfRemotes = (tbsite.NoOfRemotes == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(tbsite.NoOfRemotes),
                              GateType = tbsite.GateType,
                              NoOfRacks = (tbsite.NoOfRacks == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(tbsite.NoOfRacks),
                            };
```

My Model:

```
public class Gate
    {

        public DateTime CalledInAt { get; set; }

        public string RemoteType { get; set; }
        public int NoOfRemotes { get; set; }
        public string GateType { get; set; }
        public int NoOfRacks { get; set; }
        public string ClickToEdit { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm getting following errors.

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   Parse(System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression."}   System.SystemException
>   {System.NotSupportedException}
>
> {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression."}    System.SystemException
>   {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: You cannot use .Net function inside LINQ, because this will be converted into an actual SQL. That is the reason it is complaining about the conversion. Example = you cannot use `Convert.toInt32` as the SQL Server does not know what this function is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nilesh already pointed out in his comment

> You cannot use .Net function inside LINQ, because this will be converted into an actual SQL. That is the reason it is complaining about the conversion. Example = you cannot use Convert.toInt32 as the SQL Server does not know what this function is.

An easy fix for your problem would be to call `ToList()`. This will execute the query and populate a list with the results. After that it is possible to use `ToString()` or `Convert.ToInt32` cause the values are all in-memory and you are free to use .NET methods.

```
IEnumerable<Gate> lstGate = from tbsite in dc.tblSites.ToList()
                            select new Gate
                            {
                              CalledInAt = DateTime.Parse(tbsite.CalledInAt.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-GB", false)),
                              RemoteType = tbsite.RemoteType,
                              NoOfRemotes = (tbsite.NoOfRemotes == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(tbsite.NoOfRemotes),
                              GateType = tbsite.GateType,
                              NoOfRacks = (tbsite.NoOfRacks == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(tbsite.NoOfRacks),
                            };
```

The call `dc.tblSites.ToList()` will read all values and rows from the table. If you want to apply sorting or filtering to reduce the amount of read data, then you need to apply the `Where()` or `OrderBy()` calls before `ToList()`

Comment: I would be very careful when using this method, as you are literally calling in the whole SQL table to filter it and find one item on the client side.  while this may be an easy fix, it has massive performance implications.

Comment: @AndrewCounts yes of course. he has to apply his filter, sort and order criteria before executing the ToList().

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that error because the Select part is being sent to the server by EF
two things

1) the objects from `dc.tblSites` can be directly used.

2) if you really want to transform them first get the data from the database then create the object
`.ToArray()` is a good one.

`... from tbsite in dc.tblSites.ToArray() ...`